# Class compiled using an application server Java EE jars deployed in another application server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, weblogic

I have WebLogic (10.3.5) application server installed in a server and in an another 
server JBoss AS (7.1.1) installed.

`ServletA.java` gets compiled using Java EE specific jars in JBoss AS and deployed in WebLogic (during 
runtime WebLogic will be using its own Java EE specific jars to execute). Currently, when I access the servlet in WebLogic, I'm not getting any errors, it's working fine.

My question is, is this approach OK or will this create any problems in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you stick to the classes in the Java EE spec and don't use any JBoss specific classes or features this approach is OK.

What can still go wrong is if you rely on server specific behavior (hard to test) or run into bugs on one server.

Comment: I don't have any server JEE specific code and it's working fine in both servers. It's been more than a month and no problems so far. Recently I tried request.getServletContext(), which worked in JBoss but not in weblogic, then I used a different code to get the context. Usually I swap server jars in eclipse workspace build path to check whether my JEE related changes works or not.